# Skeleton Grid User Agent Style Sheet

Tags: html, css, grid

I just started using Skeleton grid and it has been great to me except i just added a form submit and there are a bunch of strange styles added to my submit... When i look at it from inspect elements it shows all of this

```
user agent stylesheetinput[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
padding: 1px 6px;
}
user agent stylesheetinput[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
align-items: flex-start;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
color: buttontext;
padding: 2px 6px 3px;
border: 2px outset buttonface;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
background-color: buttonface;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetinput[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
-webkit-appearance: push-button;
white-space: pre;
}
user agent stylesheetinput, input[type="password"], input[type="search"], isindex {
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
padding: 1px;
background-color: white;
border: 2px inset;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheetinput, textarea, keygen, select, button, isindex {
margin: 0em;
font: -webkit-small-control;
color: initial;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: start;
}
```

How do i get ride of this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand correctly what you're asking...

Those are user agent styles. Default styles applied by the browser. Default styles are applied to all browser elements. They're what make an h1 tag larger than an h2 tag, a body tag block, span inline, etc.. etc...

If you want to change those styles you have to override them. For example:

If you want to edit padding on the submit button, you can add this to your stylesheet:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```